# How to do lookups/get DHT data using the browser

Tags: javascript, browserify, bittorrent, dht

I have the following working in node.js to do a basic DHT `put` and `get`. I can later retrieve the same DHT by using only the `get` method and passing in the previously created infohash. What I would like to do next is look up that DHT in the browser, but I'm not having any success with browserification. Are there any libraries for the browser out there that can read DHT data by looking up an infohash?

```
// Emitter
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');
util.inherits(emitter, EventEmitter);
function emitter(){
    var self = this;
}
let e = new emitter()

//DHT
const DHT = require('bittorrent-dht')

const dht = new DHT()

let data = 'Some cool new data'

const value = Buffer.from(data, 'utf8')

dht.put({ v: value }, function (err, hash) {
  if(err) console.error('Error:', err)
  let arr = dht.toJSON()
  let infoHash = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr.values).toString()
  console.log(infoHash)

  e.emit('hash', infoHash)
})

e.on('hash', infoHash => {
    dht.get(infoHash, (err, res) => {
        if(err) console.log(err)
        let data = res.v.toString()
        console.log(data)
    })
})
```

I know that WebTorrent uses bittorrent-dht, but I'm not quite sure how I would use WebTorrent for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bittorrent DHT requires plain UDP sockets to work. Currently there are no web APIs that provide that, thus it cannot be implemented in web pages.